# Список для установки пакетов в Debian

Tags: linux, пакеты

Можно ли создать список установленных вручную пакетов Debian, чтобы в дальнейшем (например, после перестановки системы) можно было бы устанавливать эти пакеты автоматически?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да, можно. А почему ты не попробовал найти готовое решение самостоятельно?

Answer (score 2):

создать список пакетов

```
 apt-mark showmanual > manual.txt
```

Например на wsl у меня получилось

```
~$ apt-mark showmanual
aptitude
base-files
base-passwd
bash
bsdutils
dash
debootstrap
diffutils
findutils
fonts-noto
grep
gzip
hostname
imagemagick
init
ipython3
libdebconfclient0
libssl-dev
login
lua-bit32
lua-bitop
lua5.1
lua5.4
mc
ncat
ncurses-base
ncurses-bin
net-tools
nmap
openssl
pandoc
postgresql-client-14
postgresql-client-common
python3-pip
python3-pygments
python3-venv
python3.12-dev
python3.12-distutils
python3.12-venv
pythonpy
qrencode
sysvinit-utils
texlive
texlive-extra-utils
texlive-fonts-recommended
texlive-lang-chinese
texlive-lang-cyrillic
texlive-latex-base
texlive-latex-extra
texlive-latex-recommended
texlive-xetex
ubuntu-minimal
ubuntu-standard
ubuntu-wsl
whois
winpr-utils
```

Установить обратно можно так

```
sudo apt install `cat  manual.txt`
```

или так

```
xargs < manual.txt apt-get install -y
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь текстовый файл. Пишешь туда, перечисляя все пакеты:

```
sudo apt-get install package-1 package-2 итд
```

Готово. После перестановки системы просто выполняешь команду в терминале.

Comment: Такой "способ" я и сам знаю.

Comment: Жалею, что задал вопрос. Русскоязычная часть сайта, видимо, используется для демонстрации участниками своего превосходства, а не для обмена информацией.

Comment: Нет, эта часть сайта большей частью используется для демонстрации собственного неумения задать вопрос. Если ты знаешь этот способ и он тебя чем-то не устраивает, то это нужно было отразить в вопросе, с упоминанием того ЧЕМ ИМЕННО не устраивает. Чтобы желающие помочь вдруг не оказались демонстрантами своего превосходства. Телепатов тут нет.

Comment: ` создать список установленных вручную пакетов` - не понятно что тут можно не понять) я телепат!)

Comment: Ну вот у меня именно таким образом создан "список установленных вручную пакетов" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯